# Unity3D: Call an event once from multiple child gameobjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, coroutine

So I have a `script A` which calls a particular coroutine from `script B`. There are 6 `gameobjects` with `script B`, so 6 different coroutines are called in a for a loop.

Something like this

```
foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
       {
           
           if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>() != null)
           {
               child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>().CallCoroutine();
           }

       }
```

The `coroutines` runs for a while. The `coroutine` for all the 6 `gameobjects` ends at the same time. I want to send an event back to `script A` once after these `coroutines` end. But if I send an event from `script B`, the event would get triggered 6 times. What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to pass an `Action` to the coroutine for it to call when it completes, then in that `Action`, decrement a counter that all of the `Action`s have in common, and if that counter hits zero, call the event you'd like to call:

```
// B.cs

void CallCoroutine(Action callback)
{
    StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(arg1, arg2, arg3, callback));
}

IEnumerator MyCoroutine(int a, float b, string c, Action callback)
{
    // ... coroutine logic here

    callback();
}
```

```
// A.cs

int counter = 6;
Action callback = delegate() 
{ 
    if (--counter == 0) 
    { 
        LastCoroutineCompleteEvent(); 
    } 
};

foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
{
    B childB = child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>();
    if (childB != null)
    {
        childB.CallCoroutine(callback);
    }
}
```

And if the number of coroutines is variable, you can count the number of times you'll call `CallCoroutine` and set the starting value of `counter` accordingly. To be safe, you'll probably want to finish setting the starting value of `counter` before you call `CallCoroutine`. So, something like this:

```
// A.cs

int counter;
Action callback = delegate() 
{ 
    if (--counter == 0) 
    { 
        LastCoroutineCompleteEvent(); 
    } 
};

List<B> childBs
foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
{
    B childB = child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>();
    if (childB != null)
    {
        childBs.Add(childB);
    }
}

counter = childBs.Count;

foreach (B childB in childBs)
{
    childB.CallCoroutine(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have `Script A` wait for all of the coroutines to finish, and then call the event. It would look something like this:

```
IEnumerator WaitForChildren() {

    List<Coroutine> running = new List<Coroutine>();

    foreach (Transform child in allChildren) {
        if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>() != null) {
            running.Add(child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>().CallCoroutine());
        }
    }

    foreach (var coroutine in running) {
        yield return coroutine;
    }

    ChildrenFinishedEvent();
}
```

You would need to make `CallCoroutine()` return the coroutine object which would be returned by `StartCoroutine()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your CallCoroutine function a param of type bool which determines if the event should be triggered or not.

```
foreach (Transform child in allChildren)
{
   bool triggerOnce = true;
   if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>() != null)
   {
        child.gameObject.GetComponent<B>().CallCoroutine(triggerOnce);
        if(triggerOnce) { triggerOnce = false; }

   }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because it would trigger after the first called coroutine begins. Asker wants it to trigger after the last completed coroutine ends.

Comment: @Ruzihm The asker wrote that all 6 coroutines do end at the same time - in this case one needs to just have one callback. Though I admit that it's a kind of a hack it'll still work in this scenario.